# Gcm messages are not coming in marshmallow but rest all devices are receiving

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have integrated gcm notifications.
everything is working fine.
server is giving success but notifications are not coming on marshmallow.
i have tested in other versions also. they are receiving fine.

Comment: have you found the reason?

Comment: yes i solved this by setting priority

Comment: Thanks. Did your have problems with receiving gcm only in sleep mode or also when device is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at 
http://android-developers.blogspot.ae/2015/10/how-google-cloud-messaging-handles-doze.html

Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduces a new power saving feature called ‘Doze’ which may be affecting your notifications.

> when using normal priority (the default priority), there are a number
>   of different behaviors when the device is in Doze, including:
>
> The most important change is that messages will be batched for devices in Doze. When the device enters its idle maintenance window,
>   the batch of messages will be received.
>
> We discard messages whose time_to_live expires while the device is in Doze (including TTL=0).

Answer (score 1):

There is no known problem in receiving GCM messages on Marshmallow.

So I suggest first testing with one of the many GCM tester apps on the Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eboyer.gcmtester

This would allow you to debug wether it's an issue in your app or the system.